# Suitable assertion in (System)Verilog default of case statement that should never occur

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

What kind of assertion is suitable for dealing with the default case of a SystemVerilog case statement?

Here are a few approaches that come to mind:

```
default:
  $display("this should never occur")
  // because all anticipated cases are supposed to be caught above
  // and the default catch hints at an illegal or omitted case
  output = safe_value;
endcase
```

Or, instead of $display()

```
$info("this should never occur")
```

Or, in SystemVerilog

```
assert (false) $warning("this should never occur")
```

Similar situations occur in priority-coded nested if...else, where a final else is not anticipated to occur, but where it's wise to issue a warning during simulation.

I am looking to use language statements, not tasks or 'defines, and they should not pose problems with linting or synthesis.

The assertion technique should preferably still allow for a *safe* default case, even when the default case is not anticipated to occur.

Comment: I do not think that there is any disagreement. You do whatever is the best for your project and which fits methodology used by your company.  You also forgot to list *unique/priority* cases in sv which is a standard way to handle these issues.

Comment: @Serge good tip, Dave also addresses the unique/priority in his answer. As for the company methodology, the point of this is not about whether to follow an existing policy but to weigh the various approaches.

Answer (score 2):

SystemVerilog has a `priority case` and a `unique case` that creates an assertion for you if there is no `default` and no other *case item* is chosen.

Note that this works fine for sequential logic, or combinatorial logic without glitches that might trigger false errors.

Otherwise, synthesis tools ignore assertions.

Comment: Good point on the glitches, I have indeed had to resort to "assert final". I am more concerned about indeterminate circuit output (silicon or LUTs) if unique is used, rather than default. How do you suggest to use "unique" with a safe circuit default output, that also results in a simulation warning. (I don't think "priority" can solve this either?)

Comment: Probably needs to be another question as I don’t know what your design requirements are